# .bash_profile doest run on su user

Tags: bash, centos6

I have created a bash_profile in centos

```
#vi /home/hadoop/.bash_profile
```

as follow:

```
# .bash_profile
# User specific environment and startup programs
export j=1
```

However, when I do

```
[root@hadoop1 ~]# su hadoop
[hadoop@hadoop1 root]$ echo $j

[hadoop@hadoop1 root]$
```

I suppose my .bash_prfile shoud run for each su login?

Answer (score 4):

The `.bash_profile` won't load unless you use one of the `-`, `-l`, or `--login` options or login directly with that user. Checkout [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155220/bashrc-and-bash-profile-not-executed?rq=1) is from the Unix & Linux stack exchange. You can also run `man su` in the shell to see all the available options.

Comment: Can you advice if I should use .bashrc instead?or should I create /etc/profile?

Comment: I would suggest using `su -l hadoop` to start the new shell. Does the `.bash_profile` load when you start the shell like this?

Comment: Yes, .bash_profile is run when the `-l` option is used.